# How to move a folder if I can't log in to my ubuntu?

Tags: grub, troubleshooting

My Ubuntu was working great but, I was having problems with a file that I thought was not in the right location, so I decided to move a folder called boot into a folder called root, and when I restarted my computer it only shows a black screen with grub> on it.

How can I move back the boot folder to the location where it was before? I don't know a thing about Ubuntu, so please be very very specific.

Comment: You try using the CD or any other media which you used to install Ubuntu, and enter into the Recovery mode. try this link https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-boot-ubuntu-linux-rescue-mode/

Comment: Just to be clear, you are not running  `Ubuntu` or `linux` at this point, you are running `grub` (the grand unified boot loader), which is the program responsible for loading the operating system into memory. There was a /boot/grub directory which contained a configuration file and probably some programs that were used to do this. Whilst it is possible to run commands at the grub prompt to get the system up, the advice Mongrel has given to boot using your installation media is much simpler.